# Jboss - "Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS"

Tags: java, exceção, java-ee, jboss

Estão ocorrendo as seguintes exceções na minha aplicação:

```
10:52:34,506 ERROR [br.com.app.dao.NotificacaoDAO] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-77) java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,509 ERROR [br.com.app.dao.UsuarioDAO] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-55) java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,513 ERROR [br.com.app.business.NotificacaoBS] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-77) br.com.app.exceptions.DAOException: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,513 ERROR [br.com.app.dao.MensagemDAO] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,520 ERROR [br.com.app.business.MensagemBS] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) br.com.app.exceptions.DAOException: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,522 ERROR [br.com.app.controller.serversent.ListarNovasNotificacoesController] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-77) br.com.app.exceptions.BusinessException: br.com.app.exceptions.DAOException: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,512 ERROR [br.com.app.business.UsuarioBS] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-55) br.com.app.exceptions.DAOException: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,530 ERROR [br.com.app.services.UsuarioService] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-55) br.com.app.exceptions.BusinessException: br.com.app.exceptions.DAOException: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,534 ERROR [br.com.app.controller.serversent.ListarNovasMensagensController] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) br.com.app.exceptions.BusinessException: br.com.app.exceptions.DAOException: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
10:52:34,585 ERROR [br.com.app.dao.UsuarioDAO] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-66) java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/AppDS
```

Em um minuto ela disparou várias exceções como essa /\

Sempre acontece uns 5 dias após iniciar a aplicação e ela ficar 24h online.

Eu já pesquisei sobre, mas realmente não encontrei o problema, talvez poderia ser alguma conexão aberta, mas eu fecho todas as conexões.

Alguém sabe o porque?

**Obs:** Eu uso o JBOSS 7.1.1

Answer (score 3):

A causa mais comum para esse tipo de erro é que o banco não tem mais conexões para distribuir. Se você está liberando as conexões após o uso, pode ser que alguma outra parte do seu programa ou componente esteja abrindo conexões.

Pode ser um problema de carga também. Talvez você tenha que configurar o banco para suportar mais conexões abertas ao mesmo tempo. Mas como você diz que o problema ocorre depois de certo tempo, parece algo cumulativo.

O que você pode fazer para solucionar o problema é verificar quantas conexões estão abertas (e mesmo monitorar isto, se necessário). Isso pode ser feito pelo JBoss CLI ou através de ferramentas de monitoração. Não irão solucionar o problema mas irão mostrar se há um vazamento de conexões e lhe dar recursos para tentar resolver o problema.

Aqui tem informações de como obter estatísticas de datasources através do JBoss CLI (command line interface): https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes#CLIRecipes-Readstatisticsofactivedatasources

Ele vai retornar várias propriedades que você pode usar para descobrir o que está acontecendo. Veja os valores que estiverem nestas aqui:

1. "ActiveCount" => "50" - Total de conexões disponíveis e ativas no
   momento
2. "AvailableCount" => "50" - Total de conexões disponíveis
   para uso
3. "CreatedCount" => "30" - Total de novas conexões criadas
4. "DestroyedCount" => "0" - Total de conexões destruídas
5. "MaxUsedCount" => "50" - Total de conexões usadas

Aqui há alguns exemplos de monitoração de dados de datasources no JBoss: https://community.jboss.org/thread/175957?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, como o próprio stacktrace diz... ocorreu um erro fazer um lookup do "java:/AppDS" dentro da sua classe NotificacaoDAO.
Provavelmente você está com algo assim: (voce não esclareceu muito bem os detalhes)

```
public class NotificacaoDAO {

@Resource(lookup = "java:/AppDS")
private Datasource ds

...
}
```

A definição do endereço JNDI no caso do JBoss aconselho o segunite padrão(Para Datasources):

```
java:jboss/datasources/MEU_DS
```

Oque acontece também é queessa DS não está corretamente registrado OU você não tem o driver instalado corretamente:
Na [DOCUMENTAÇÃO](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7?_sscc=t) está bem claro esse processo.